# Angularjs - Second view not updated after updating model and location

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-routing

I have one controller that manages two views and I would like to update the second view according to the selected entry into the first view.

==> First view: stores.html:

```
 <div>
    <ol class="breadcrumb" ng-repeat="store in stores">
        <li>
            {{store.Name}} &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="selectStore(store.Index)">
                {{store.Alerts.length}} Alerts
            </a>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

==> Second view store-selected.html:

```
<div>{{message}}</div>

<div>
    {{selectedStore.Name}}
</div>
```

==> angular routes:

```
.when('/store', {
                controller: 'StoreCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/store/stores.html'
            })
            .when('/store-selected', {
                controller: 'StoreCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/store/store-selected.html'
            })
```

==> angular controller:

```
.controller('StoreCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
            $scope.message = "Init message";

            $scope.stores = [
                { Index: 0, Name: 'Store A', Alerts: [{ id: 1 }] },
                { Index: 1, Name: 'Store B', Alerts: [{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }] },
                { Index: 2, Name: 'Store C', Alerts: [{ id: 4 }] }
            ];

            $scope.selectedStore = $scope.stores[0];

            $scope.selectStore = function (storeIndex) {
                $scope.message = "click event called!";
                $scope.selectedStore = $scope.stores[storeIndex];

                $location.path('/store-selected');

            };
        }])
```

the second view is displayed but the update of the model is not reflected into it.

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of route you want to use `$routeParams`.

```
.when('store:storeId', {
    controller: 'StoreCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'views/store/store-selected.html'
})
```

then in ctrl

```
.controller('StoreCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $routeParams.storeId;
});
```

Doing so on a single UI you would want to use angular-ui-router or something.